# Why do I get an error code 503 response when trying to access my CartoDB dashboard?

Tags: carto

One pressing problem is that when I try to access my tables or visualizations on the CartoDB web app, I get this [error page](https://github.com/CartoDB/cartodb/blob/master/public/500.html). My account is ['safedev'](https://safedev.cartodb.com/)

**Something that may or may not be relevant, but was not true before now:**

When I try to `q=SELECT CDB_UserTable()&api_key=[my-api-key]` with the SQL api (via POST, but not via GET), I get:

503 Service Unavailable

## Error 503 Service Unavailable

Service Unavailable

#### Guru Meditation:

XID: 175897971 (EDIT: Will not match this number exactly - Jake)

---

Varnish cache server

However, **if I do not supply my api_key** (ie. `q=SELECT CDB_UserTables()`), I get normal results.

Also I can still get data from my tables via the SQL API, with or without api_key. For example,
`q=SELECT * FROM "table"&api_key=[my-api-key]` returns what I expect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update: Found the 503 issue.

You have at least one table whose name has a dot inside, and this triggered a probelm due to wrong escaping in one place of our cartodb-postgresql extension code.

I'm preparing a fix for the issue ([link to issue](https://github.com/CartoDB/cartodb/issues/1368)), but reloading the postgresql extension takes a bit of time (plus it needs to travel all users databases), so initially expect to have it fixed by tuesday midday GMT+1 time.

Sorry for the inconveniences.

**Question**: How did you create a table with a dot on its name, using the SQL API?

---

About the Varnish error performing a POST, I've filled an internal ticket (as that is likely a problem of cartodb.com).

---

Update 2:

After checking locally I couldn't reproduce, so checked your database and the problen was a table named `table_with"quote` IIRC.

While quotes at table names are alowed at Postgres, we surely don't allow them and this change has a bigger impact than just a bugfix, so I've filled another ticket (https://github.com/CartoDB/cartodb/issues/1428) but is not a priority, and for the time being you shouldn't create tables with quotes on them.

I've performed an ALTER TABLE on the offending one removing the quote so your dashboard should work again.

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't tell you with absolute certainty how we might have created a table with a dot in its name. However, I can give you a couple likely scenarios:
1. We created a table over the SQL API with the name as you see it, and then (in a separate query) called `SELECT CDB_Cartodbfy('table_name')`
2. We created an empty table in the CartoDB tables dashboard and renamed it to the name you saw.

I might be able to tell better if I knew the name of the offending table.

Comment: I don't mean to make a fuss, but it's Friday now and my tables dashboard is still inaccessible..

Comment: Sorry, I'll take a look again on monday. StackExchange notified me of this comment 20 min ago, no yesterday :(

In any case, it is possible that despite my fixes CartoDB Editor is still not ready for table names containing dots. We don't allow then from the editor nor imports, we're working to fully add support from SQL API created tables but "full freedom" introduces problems like your case.

If you're in a hurry I could just rename the table with a dot.

Comment: Problem fixed, you had a nasty `table_with"quote` table breaking everything. Sadly we don't support those. For more details check the updated Answer.

Sorry for the problems caused

Comment: Thanks @Kartones, I'll make sure that we don't allow any more quotes to find their way into table names